# Сокет отправка файла, добавляется лишний байт

Tags: android, сокет, клиент-сервер, lazarus, synapse

Такой вопрос: отправляю файл с сервера на клиент, сервер написан на лазарусе с использовнием synapse код отправки:

```
tstimgstream:=TFileStream.Create('C:/testimg.jpg',fmOpenRead);
tstimgstream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning); 
   if Socket.LastError = 0 then
begin
Socket.SendString('ImageFile:='+'testimg.jpg'+'^'+IntToStr(tstimgstream.Size));
   T.Socket.SendStream(tstimgstream);    
end;
tstimgstream.free;
```

код приёма:

```
String[] srvStringsubparse = DataFromServerStringArray[0].split(":=");
if (srvStringsubparse[0].equals("ImageFile")) {
if (srvcpermissionWriteStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && srvcpermissionReadStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
return;
}
File SavingPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
SavingPath = new File(SavingPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + MAIN_DIR_SD);
if (!SavingPath.exists()) {
SavingPath.mkdirs();
}
SavingPath = new File(SavingPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/.cache");
if (!SavingPath.exists()) {    
  SavingPath.mkdirs();
}
SavingFile = new File(SavingPath, srvStringsubparse[1]);
} else {
}
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(SavingFile);
int imglength = Integer.parseInt(DataFromServerStringArray[1]);                                        
byte[] bytes = new byte[imglength];
int count, total = 0;
while ((count = inputstr.read(bytes)) > -1) {
total += count;
out.write(bytes, 0, count);
if (total >= imglength) break;
}
out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
SendReqConnectService("BlockRecived");
```

и в принципе код работает, файл уходит и принимается клиентом, но с лишним символм в заголовке, если его удалить то файл нормально открывается, подобная проблема уже описывалать тут: [вопрос от user200303](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623268/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-java), но отправляющая сторона была тоже написана на java, и автор вопроса решил проблему удалением `out.reset();` на отправляющей стороне при `private ObjectOutputStream out;`
а что можно сделать в моем случае, откуда может взятся этот лишний символ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась! Нужно было использовать метод `SendStreamRaw(const Stream: TStream); virtual;`

Цитата из справки по TBlockSocket:

> Public    procedure SendBlock(const Data: AnsiString); virtual;
>
> Send data as one block to socket. Each block begin with 4 bytes with length of data >in block. This 4 bytes is added automaticly by this function.
> Public     procedure SendStreamRaw(const Stream: TStream); virtual;
>
> Send data from stream to socket.
> Public     procedure SendStream(const Stream: TStream); virtual;
>
> Send content of stream to socket. It using SendBlock method

Те. метод который я использовал отправляет поток блоками, а нужно было отправлять поток таким как он есть